# Help with steps for sprinkler blowout for winter

Tags: sprinkler-system, air-compressor

Someone helped use an air compressor to do the sprinkler blowout last year, but this year I have to do it myself and can't remember exactly what the steps were, especially which valves to turn on and off and when, and sequence of steps. The videos I watch online all have more extensive systems/boxes out side which I don't (or can't see) and don't seem to be needed. Here are couple of photos: one is a photo of what I have outside, and this is where the compressor was connected. The second is a photo of basement wall where you can see the sprinkler water line and valve.

It would be great if, based on these pictures, someone can tell me the sequence of steps I need to perform. I have two zones, controlled by a Rachio controller.[image][image]

Comment: What compressor did you use last time?  And where are the zone valves?  They should be in a box with a green (or black) plastic cover.  If you don't know, follow the cable from the controller to them.  If they are buried in soil like that blowout valve you should take this opportunity to unearth them and install a valve box.

Comment: Depending on the compressor you want to keep the pressure low, below 60 pounds output.  Do not need a 100 pound plus pressure.

Comment: The black wire going through your wall looks like cable from a controller to solenoid valves. Your photos don't provide enough information to detail the process you want detailed. Typically you manually open each circuit's solenoid valve before blowing out that circuit. You need to trace that black wire to the solenoid valves if you don't already know where they are. Amend your question with a photo of the valves.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I think the valve box (if there is one) is buried, and the black wire leads to it. Last couple of years, we didn't do anything with it. What I can't remember is 1) whether I activate the Rachio controller for a zone as I perform the blowout and 2) whether the faucet in the blowout valve outside pictured was open during the process or not.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the air compressor connects down stream of the back flow valve (yours, I assume, is that check valve inside and sandwiched between the PVC fittings). You can use the controller to open each circuit as you blow it out, but this is typically done manually by hand-manipulating the solenoid valves. If that faucet isn't where you hook up the air compressor during the process, then it would be closed. Compressors can put out much more pressure than water systems, so keep the pressure down around 40 psi until you hear water escaping the system. Then you can ramp up the air pressure because the air is flowing through the system instead of exerting its pressure against pipes and fittings.

I can imagine your faucet being an irrigation circuit designed to drive an above ground hose. In that case you would open the faucet, blow out the circuit, and then close the circuit. If your faucet implements the more likely scenario of branching off the irrigation line upstream of your valves, then you should open the faucet and blow out this line too, but you'll have to keep the faucet closed as you blow out your irrigation circuits.

Comment: Thanks a lot popham.  Some follow up questions:
1) If I open each zone during blowout using the controller, would I keep the water line open (black lever in wall photo) ?
2) I did connect the compressor to that faucet during blowout last year. So then I would keep it open during blowout ?
3) In the second paragraph of your response. -- I do not know which of the two possibilities you mention is correct here, but there is an outside tap next to the faucet in the outside photo, and it probably is being fed by the vertical pipe you see in the inside photo (with the blue shutoff lever).

Comment: The water should be shut off the whole time you're trying to remove water from the water lines. Don't turn it back on. The water lines will have water in them again.

Comment: If you're pushing air through any fittings/faucets/etc. to blow out your system, then these fittings/faucets/etc. must be open to allow the air flow through them.

Comment: If you attached the air to the faucet last time, then most likely it is upstream of the solenoid valve(s). If you open up a solenoid valve, push air into the system, and nothing happens, then the faucet may be downstream of the solenoid valve, requiring its circuit and the circuit you're evacuating to be open simultaneously. I suspect that you would remember doing that last year, so this second scenario is highly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks again. I know some of my questions were very naive but I wanted to be as clear as I could. Thanks for your patience in helping out. Assuming the upstream scenario, these are then my steps:
1) close black water valve inside
2) Connect compressor to faucet and open it
3) Open Zone via Rachio as if watering (will some water already in the line come out at this point ? )
4) Run compressor staring from 40 psi. Should see water coming out through sprinkler heads initially and then only air -- stop compressor.
5) Repeat 3-4 for the other zone.
Does this sounds right ?

Comment: I think I have at least been partially successful. One quick question: as you monitor the pressure, should I be looking at tank pressure or outlet pressure ? I charged the tank up to 50 psi, opened a zone via controller, opened the air outlet on compressor. Water started coming out first then mist, and then not much except a bit of fizz. But the pressure readings dropped pretty quickly so I am wondering if I should be charging to much higher tank pressure and try to keep compressor on and try to maintain 40/50 or more on the outlet ?

Comment: @Sandhitsu Das, you should charge the tank to its maximum if you can regulate its outlet pressure. The reserve pressure, as you've observed, will give you a larger volume of air to push through the system. The 40psi is to avoid overstressing the sprinkler parts, so once there's a steady stream of air coming out of a sprinker head, then you can increase the pressure. I suspect, however, that the extra volume of air you get at 40psi will do more good than the extra pressure that you get at 50psi. Maybe it differs from system to system. I don't know. I would even try 10 psi.

Comment: Thank you. Even though pressure dropped, there wasn't much coming out of the sprinkler heads anymore. If I now push air again at an outlet pressure of 40 or 50 psi, how do I know I am done ?

Comment: @Sandhitsu Das, professionals use a massive air reservoir to push lots of volume at high pressure. DIY is going to leave a lot more water in the system. My intuition is that half empty everywhere is pretty good. As water in that pipe expands, the half circle can shift upward to avoid stressing the pipe. At the ends of such a pipe, however, there's still a tight spot for the ice to break things.

Comment: Makes sense. Hopefully my final question -- and you have been so helpful, really appreciate your time. How do I know I am done ? I want to do more with higher tank pressure but don't want to keep pushing air for longer than I need to.

Comment: @Sandhitsu Das, once there's a clear path for air to escape, then lots of pressure shouldn't hurt. When the inertia of water resists, your fittings and tubing will experience the full air pressure. Without obstruction, most of the pressure gets converted to air velocity. And "done" depends on your criteria. As more and more water gets removed, your system gets reduced to fewer and fewer risk areas, and the risk in those areas goes down. Between the valves and the water supply is the painful to fix area, so that's the really critical area.